# I am unable to fetch email of friends using android-facebook-sdk

Tags: android

I am unable to fetch email of friends using android facebook sdk..
Is there any way to find them...

I am using the following code:

```
private void onClickPickFriends() {
        final FriendPickerFragment fragment = new FriendPickerFragment();

        setFriendPickerListeners(fragment);

        showPickerFragment(fragment);
    }

    private void setFriendPickerListeners(final FriendPickerFragment fragment) {
        fragment.setOnDoneButtonClickedListener(new FriendPickerFragment.OnDoneButtonClickedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDoneButtonClicked(PickerFragment<?> pickerFragment) {
                onFriendPickerDone(fragment);
            }
        });
    }

    private void showPickerFragment(PickerFragment<?> fragment) {
        fragment.setOnErrorListener(new PickerFragment.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onError(PickerFragment<?> pickerFragment,
                    FacebookException error) {
                String text = getString(R.string.exception, error.getMessage());
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getfrnds.this, text,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        });

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(null).commit();

        controlsContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // We want the fragment fully created so we can use it immediately.
        fm.executePendingTransactions();

        fragment.loadData(false);
    }

    private void onFriendPickerDone(FriendPickerFragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.popBackStack();

        String results = "";

        List<GraphUser> selection = fragment.getSelection();
        tags = selection;
        if (selection != null && selection.size() > 0) {
            ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (GraphUser user : selection) {
                names.add(user.getName() + ":" + user.getId());
                fbid = user.getId();
            }
            results = TextUtils.join(", ", names);
        } else {
            results = getString(R.string.no_friends_selected);
        }

        showAlert(getString(R.string.you_picked), results);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have access to it first ! on facebook developer page.
 If you already have then just you get it like this:

```
String email=null;
 for (GraphUser user : selection) {
            names.add(user.getName() + ":" + user.getId());
            fbid = user.getId();
            email=user.getEmail();

        }
```

But for best practice make a Friend class with parameters what you need  and make a list with type Friend.

```
ArrayList<Friend> names = new ArrayList<Friend>();
 for (GraphUser user : selection) {
            Friend fb_friend = new Friend(your,parameters,etc);
            names.add(fb_friend);

        }
```

its better this way than parsing a String. You can get what you need from your object.